# How to make my Python code behave like arduino serial monitor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

I am using `serial communication` with `Arduino Leonardo`.

When I test with Serial Monitor it seems to works fine. When I enter "1 500 500", mouse tends to move as expected.

But when I test with python, mouse does not seem to move and that results in `"Num : 1"`

How to make Python behave like an ***arduino serial monitor*** ?

Below is my python code :

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM10',
    baudrate=9600,
)
num = str.encode('1')
ser.write(num)
ser.write(b'500')
ser.write(b'500')

while True:
    cnt = 0
    if ser.readable():
        cnt = cnt+1
        print("Num :", cnt)
        res = ser.readline()
        res = res.decode()
        print(res)
```

Arduino code

```
#include "Keyboard.h" // Keyboard library
#include "Mouse.h"    // Mouse library
#include <MouseTo.h>

int inNum;
int inX;
int inY;

// Procedure of pressing key and moving mouse
void procedure();


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Keyboard.begin();
  Mouse.begin();
  MouseTo.setCorrectionFactor(0.5);
  MouseTo.setScreenResolution(1920, 1080);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    inNum = Serial.parseInt();
    procedure(inNum);
  }

}

void procedure(int num){
  switch (num)
  {
    case 1:
      inX = Serial.parseInt();
      inY = Serial.parseInt();
      MouseTo.setTarget(inX, inY);
      while(!MouseTo.move()){};
      Mouse.click(MOUSE_LEFT);
      delay(200);
      MouseTo.setTarget(0, 0);
      while(!MouseTo.move()){};
      Serial.write("Done");
      break;
    case 2:
      MouseTo.setTarget(960, 540);
      while(!MouseTo.move()){};
      break;
    default:
      //MouseTo.setTarget(1920, 1080);
      //while(!MouseTo.move()){};
      Serial.write("default");
      Serial.write(num);
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues preventing you from getting what you want.

First, the way you parse integers on your Arduino code is expecting a separator. It reads until it finds something that is not a number. To fix that just add spaces on the strings you send, or colon or whatever you like. Otherwise `Serial.parseInt()` will not be able to read anything because you are only sending numbers from Python.

Second, you cannot read in Python with `serial.readline()` if you use raw write (`Serial.write()`) from the Arduino. Again, Python is expecting a line terminating caharcter. To fix that, add `\r\n` to the string you send or use `Serial.println()` instead. If you don't want to add those terminating characters you can read bytes in a loop until the buffer is empty.